# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database, macos

I am trying to clone a repo and run it on my local machine. I don't have a DB created and I am trying to manually create my database.yml file (my first time doing this). I am not quite sure what i'm doing and keep getting errors about connecting to the MySql server. Here's my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: db/app_development
  username: root
  password:
```

I also tried localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, both give me errors when trying to create the db by doing 'bundle exec rake db:create' ...i get this error:

```
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
Couldn't create database for {"username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"db/app_development", "host"=>"127.0.0.1", "password"=>nil}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

I know i'm doing something wrong but I can't quite figure out what it is. Do I need to start the mysql server or something?

This is the output when I run mysqld_safe:

```
120111 20:35:39 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/Matthew-Bermans-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
120111 20:35:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
120111 20:35:41 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Matthew-Bermans-MacBook-Air.local.pid ended
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the details are correct? (You could show us a terminal session of you successfully connecting to the database?)

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL directly on your terminal by running mysql -uroot ?. Also try "localhost" instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: Try either mysqld_safe or sudo mysqld_safe from the terminal. Your database isn't running.

Comment: I have no idea if the details are correct...that's probably one of the problems. I just added whatever I thought would work because I don't have a database yet...because I can't run db:create...it's kind of a chicken and egg situation and I'm not sure what to do. I think I got the steps mixed up...I get this when doing mysql -uroot: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Is your server even listening on that address? What does 'netstat -ntap' show for port 3306

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: app_development
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Then do your `rake db:create` to create it from rails.
or
in mysql do `create database db_name`
and then the above code for `:development` will let you use it.

**Update:**  Matthew first needs to get mySQL installed on his (Mac) machine.
I directed him to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: No i get the same error:Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

how would I know what to put in the database: field without actually having a database created? basically, I just cloned this repo and trying to get it to work. I don't have a database created and I don't have a proper database.yml setup yet. What is the step by step process to get this to work? I bundle installed everything and it passed fine.

Comment: I made the database.yml file exactly as you have shown. I then did bundle exec rake db:create (needed bundle exec), but I get this error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2). I am not sure how to do it "in mysql"

Comment: Added socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock to the yml file and got this error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Matthew, lets do comment cleanup! (i.e. delete the chats).

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly mention your `port: 3306` in your database.yml

If that doesn't work then executed

```
netstat -tupln
```

and check if MySQL is listening to port `3306` or not

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try executing the following to check if you have a connection to mysql from command prompt (without Ruby on Rails).

```
mysql -u root
```

If cannot connect you probably specified and password.  You will need to either remember it or reinstall MySQL.  If you can, then create your database:

```
create database app_development;
```

Last but no the least, remove prefix 'db/' from database.yml. You don't need a full path:

```
database: app_development
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind what database software you use (I don't think you specified whether you needed MySQL or just wanted to get the repo to work), you might try using SQLite3 instead. SQLite3 doesn't run a server or use ports, so it might be easier for you to get setup.

Try imitating the rails default database.yml, which looks like:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Then add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It can also be solved by changing MySQL version. Had the same issue with some project which was developed using **MySQL 5.5** but installed version in my mac was MySQL 5.7 so I had to downgrade my version and it worked for me.